# Changing One Field in MySQL Database Breaks Visual Studio Report

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, reporting-services, visual-studio-2013

I have a project I'm working on that pulls data from a MySQL database, I read the data and do some calculations to be used to display charts and graphs, and finally have the information that was calcuated compiled in a PDF report generated from a ReportViewer. The report worked fine so I thought I'd test out making changes to the database.

There is a field in one table called "name", it's type is NVAR CHAR(MAX). To accomodate this type I read the "name" and convert it to a string using:

```
Convert.ToString(reader[2]); //reader is the object retrieved from the SQL query
```

As said before, this works fine until I change the "name" field in one table. I've changed it from a numerical string such as "2323" or "1 " (notice the space, which still works) to something arbitrary like "TEST", "TEST RUN", and "TEST " (notice the space). The program doesn't complain until I make this change at which point I'm given the following error:

```
Warning: Warnings occurred while executing the subreport "Subreport 1".(rsWarningExecutingSubreport)
Warning: An error occurred while executing the subreport "Subreport 1" Instance: 323iT4R0x0S0): Data retrieval failed for the subreport, 'Subreport 1', located at: MyCompanyReports.Reports.Measurement.rdlc. Please check the log files for more information.  (rsErrorExecutingSubreport)
```

I've searched around with this error and noticed that the following lines being in the wrong order was and issue, I think I have them in the correct order because I've successfully create reports with this configuration:

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(LocalReport_SubreportProcessing);
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

What are some things that could be going wrong that cause this issue? I'm at my wits end.

I'll post what code I can if needed.

Thanks

EDIT:
For clarification, the report is being rendered to a PDF file. The PDF is still generated but instead of my charts/graphs, I am given the error string. The error occurs directly after this line:

```
renderedBytes = this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.Render(reportype, devinfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streams, out warnings);
```

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around this. What's the root problem as it stands now? Can you boil it down to a single line question? E.I. "Why does {which dev environment} throw {x error} when I change a MySql cell from 'numeric' string to alphanumeric string?" You're using BIDS to create an RDL, right? Is the RDL throwing the error or are you catching it in C# in debug?

Comment: Why does Visual Studio 2013 (Reporting Services) crash with a rsWarningExecutingSubreport error when I change a MySQL cell from a numeric string to a string containing other characters?

I don't know what BIDS is. I'm using RDLC files to make up the report.

I'm unable to catch any exception with even a blanket try/catch block over everything that is running. I assume the RDLC file throws the warning but the app crashes either way.